# Child element not stretching parent vertically

Tags: html, css

I have #rightcontent and #rightrule next to #bodycontent, all inside of #bodywrapper with #footer below.

#bodywrapper will stretch down when content is added to #rightcontent but not when added to #bodycontent. #bodywrapper needs to stretch down based on #bodycontent so that #footer sits right against it.

```
#bodywrapper {
width: 1000px;
background-color: #000;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: solid;
border-top-color: #FF0000;
border-right-color: #434343;
border-bottom-color: #434343;
border-left-color: #434343;
color: #FFF;
height:100%;
display:block;
clear:none;
height:auto;
}
#topfade {
background-image:url(img/top_body_background.jpg);
background-repeat-y:no-repeat;
display:block;
min-height:150px;
width:100%;
background-color:#000000
}   

#Bodycontent {
width: 725px;
padding:15px;
top: -150px;/*newly added*/
text: #FFF;
float:left;
display:block;
}
#rightcontent {
margin-left:765px;
margin-top: -170px;
padding-left: 10px;
vertical-align:top;
display:block;
}
#rightrule {
margin-left:755px;
margin-top: -125px;
vertical-align:top;
width:3px;
height:100%;
}

#footer {
background-image:url(img/footer_background.jpg);
background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
text-align:center;
size: 18pt;
vertical-align:bottom;
color:#FFF;
margin:0 auto;
border-width: 1px;
border-left-style: solid;
border-right-style:solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color:#434343;
display:block;
min-height:70px;
width:1000px;
background-color:#000000;
border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
clear:left;
 }
```

Comment: Could you link us to an example page? ie jsfiddle.net...

Comment: please share your html too.. use cssdeck or jsfiddle.com

Comment: This will not not solve your question, but you should use shorthand CSS for borders:    
border: 1px solid #434343;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-top-color: #FF0000;

Comment: also use `display:table;`

Comment: `#Bodycontent` has `float`. Floating elements do not contribute to the height of their parent. Also, are you sure you are using "Bodycontent" with an uppercase B everywhere? ID names are case sensitive. And the newly added `top: -150px` will not do anything for non-positioned elements.